# Adding seconds in time

Tags: php, datetime

I don't know how to add seconds to the current time. Here is my code of saving time.

```
$timereg = date("g:i:s A", time());
```

For example the time is exactly 9:30:00

I just want to make it 9:30:02, like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you can do

```
$timereg = date("g:i:s A", time() + 2);
```

And I believe it will show the current time +2 seconds.

Comment: The + 2 worked a bit. But, it changes the hour also. When i input the first, the time is 06:15:03, but for the second one, the time became 10:15:05

Comment: Because ``time()`` returns the number of seconds passed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, adding a '2' means you add 2 seconds from the current time. And what do you mean by first input and second input?

Comment: I'm trying to record the regtime of the users. Whenever a user register, the earliest user's time will be updated to the time of the 2nd user + 2 seconds. For example. The first user timereg is 1:00:00, then the 2nd user registers, time is 1:00:30 then the first user's time should be updated to 1:00:32.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to ask that in another question, with your code examples so that we can help you.

Comment: Maybe it's because of this? 

date_default_timezone_set('Singapore');

I'm using the singapore's timezone.

Comment: I've managed to answer this problem by inserting the date_default_timezone_set('Singapore') inside the time() function. The code is now 

$timereg = date("g:i:s A", time(date_default_timezone_set('Singapore')) + 2);

Comment: If so you can just put ``date_default_timezone_set`` at the beginning of the file and it will automatically apply the timezone to the rest of the date and time function in the file. Best solution of course will be to put it in ``php.ini``.